# Compact way of assigning same handler to many events

Tags: c#, winforms, events, code-duplication

In my user control code I noticed lots of events with the same handler:

```
btnMas.MouseDown += MyMouseDown;
btnMenos.MouseDown += MyMouseDown;
txtValue.MouseDown += MyMouseDown;
lblMax.MouseDown += MyMouseDown;
lblMin.MouseDown += MyMouseDown;
lblName.MouseDown += MyMouseDown;
```

Is there a more compact way to write this? As in iterating over a collection of events, or using lambdas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're subscribing to the same event on many objects, and that event is exposed by some base class, you could use:

```
var controls = new Control[] { btnMas, btnMenos, txtValue,
                               lblMax, lblMin, lblName };
foreach (var control in controls)
{
    control.MouseDown += MyMouseDown;
}
```

I'm not sure that's *really* any cleaner, mind you. Of course it becomes a lot cleaner if you need to do several different operations to the same set of controls.

EDIT: Given the extra information, it's really as simple as:

```
foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
{
    control.MouseDown += MyMouseDown;
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that if these groups mean something, and you find yourself doing several operations on collections of controls like this you should give the variable a name that reflects what the group of controls represents.

Comment: Actually, they are all components of my user control. Now that I think about it, I can just use `this.Controls`, no need to create another collection. Like in Robert Harvey's answer.

Comment: @dario_ramos: So are they *all* the controls in `this.Controls`, or just selected ones?

Comment: @Jon Skeet: In this particular case, it's all of them

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach (var control in myForm.Controls)
{
    string name = control.GetType().Name;
    if (name  == "TextBox" || name  == "Label" || name  == "Button")
    {
        control.MouseDown += MyMouseDown;
    }
}
```

If you want to select the controls specifically, you can use this `In` extension:

```
public static bool In<T>(this T obj, params T[] values)
{
    for (int i=0; i < values.Length; i++)
    {
         if (object.Equals(obj, values[i]))
             return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Like so:

```
foreach (var control in myForm.Controls.Where(c => c.Name.In(
    "btnMas", "btnMenos", "txtValue", "lblMax", "lblMin", "lblName"))
{
    control.MouseDown += MyMouseDown;
}
```

Comment: +1, this is nice if I want to exclude or include specific controls